# The cell culture has a morphology typical for (of?) a suspension cell culture

Tags: prepositions

From a text I'm translating into English (I used a colon, but these phrases are really in adjacent table cells):

> Cell culture morphology: has a morphology typical **for** a suspension cell culture.

I first wrote **for**, but then recalled [this question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139622/typical-of-or-typical-for), and became uncertain.

Would **of** be acceptable in this case? To me, **for** looks much more natural.

Comment: Using **of** is perhaps a little more formal, but **for** is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **for** a suspension cell culture.

is correct as in this paper's title

> [Occurrence of Particles with Morphology Characteristics Which Are Typical **for** Certain Kinds of Nuclear Activity](https://www.iaea.org/safeguards/symposium/2010/Documents/PapersRepository/082.pdf)